# Definition of wreath product in James-Kerber

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters, wreath-product

I am little confused about the definition of wreath product in section 4.1 of [The Representation Theory of the Symmetric Group](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201135159) by Gordon James and Adalbert Kerber.

The definition is given as below.

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $S_n$. Denoting by
>   $G^{\mathbf{n}}$  the set of all mappings from $\mathbf{n} = \{1,
>  \ldots, n\}$ into $G$:
>
> $$ G^{\mathbf{n}} := \{f | f : \mathbf{n} \to G\}, $$
>
> we put
>
> $$ G \text{wr} H := G^{\mathbf{n}} \times H = \{(f; \pi) | f :
>  \mathbf{n} \to G \text{ and } \pi \in H\} $$

Then the authors add as follows.

> For $f \in G^{\mathbf{n}}$ and $\pi \in H$ we define $f_\pi := f \circ
>  \pi^{-1}$
>
> It is easy to check that for $\pi' \in H$
>
> $$ (f_\pi)_{\pi'} = f_{\pi' \pi}. $$
>
> Furthermore, we introduce a multiplication on $G^{\mathbf{n}}$ by
>
> $$ (ff')(i) := f(i) \cdot f'(i), i \in \mathbf{n}. $$
>
> Using this, one easily verifies that $G \text{ wr } H$ together with
>   the composition defined by
>
> $$ (f; \pi) (f'; \pi') := (ff^{'}_\pi; \pi \pi') $$
>
> forms a group, the wreath product of $G$ by $H$.

In the definition given in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product), $G^\mathbf{n}$ is defined as a direct product of $G$ with itself of order $n$ and the product with $H$ is a semidirect product.

Why are these two definitions different? Thanks.

PS. I have added more details at Eric's advice.

Comment: Are you sure that's the whole definition?  Do they not later describe what the multiplication operation is?

Comment: @EricWofsey, I actually found one after you suggested and added it to the question.

Comment: That's a multiplication on $G^\mathbf{n}$, but what about on the wreath product itself?

Comment: @EricWofsey, more details added. Thanks.

Comment: The definitions are not different.

Comment: For finite $n$ the definitions are equivalent, but the Wikipedia definition gets awkward if one wants to take an infinite $n$. Therefore many texts prefer the function version,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions are exactly the same.  By definition, if $A$ and $B$ are groups and $\varphi:B\to\operatorname{Aut}(A)$ is a homomorphism, their semidirect product is defined as the set $A\times B$ with multiplication defined by $$(a,b)\cdot(a',b')=(a\varphi(b)(a'),bb').$$  This is exactly the definition you quote, in the case $A=G^\mathbf{n}$, $B=H$, and $\varphi$ is defined by $\varphi(\pi)(f)=f_\pi$.